# Can I set a global base path for get_template_part?

Tags: get-template-part, configuration

Is there a way to apply a global setting, so that [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) always uses a predefined base path? For example, I always put my templates in a directory called 'template-parts', and it'd be nice to not have to always include that in the first argument string.

I know I could probably call a custom function that calls `get_template_part`, but I was wondering if there was a slightly more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Frankly, having your own function that calls get_template_part() internally is an elegant solution if you ask me. Plus it’s less likely to cause any issues with anything else that might try to use that function (as unlikely as that is, but it’s good to play things safe).

Comment: I assumed nothing else would need to use that function – but's you're right, that's probably not a wise assumption to make. Custom function it is.